# How to sum values returned by 3 different methods?

Tags: java, swing, methods, sum, return

I'm having trouble with summing up 3 different values in JAVA.
I'm using Swing and there are 3 different Combo-Boxes. For each selected item in each combo-box, the event listener should return a different value.
E.G.: I have one combo-box with different beverages (each one has a price) and another with different foods (again, each one has a price).
something like this:

**EDITED:** for each Combo-box, I got an array of strings with different items (foods and beverages).

E.g:

```
jCbeverages = new javax.swing.JComboBox();

jCbeverages.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {

    "Expresso- R$3.80",
    "Latte- R$6.80",
    "Cappuccino- R$6.80",

}));

jCbeverages.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jCbebidasActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});

getContentPane().add(jCbeverages);
jCbeverages.setBounds(40, 340, 300, 20);
```

**AND THE EVENT LISTENER OF THE ABOVE IS THIS:**

```
  public double jCbeveragesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                          
     int beverage= jCbeverage.getSelectedIndex();
     double priceBev= 0;
     switch (beverage){
        case (0):
           priceBev=3.80;
           break;
        case (1):
           priceBev=4.60;
           break;
        case (2):
           priceBev=4.60;
           break;
     }
     return priceBev;
  }
```

**The same occurs with the foods**

```
  public double jCfoodsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
     int food = jCfoods.getSelectedIndex();
     double priceFood=0;
     switch (food){
        case (0):
           priceFood=3.00;
           break;
        case (1):
           priceFood=4.00;
           break;
        case (2):
           priceFood=4.00;
           break;
     }
     return priceFood;  
  }
```

And I need to show the Total Price, which is `priceBev+priceFood`

But I've tried a lot of things and I can't. I thought the problem was with the scopes, but all my methods are `public` so, I don't think the problem is in that.
**Note:**I'm sorry, I had typed `getItemCount()` but it was a mistake, I got the wrong part of my code. `getSelectedIndex()`, like some of you said, is the correct. 
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Well, calling `getItemCount()` isn't going to give you the selected food or beverage.

Comment: Actually, it gives. I've tested it by printing each value in the console, and it works. The problem is with the sum

Answer (score 2):

Like @ortis and @mbw said you should do something like that:

```
public class JavaApplication2 {

    private static JComboBox c1;
    private static JComboBox c2;
    private static JLabel sumLabel = new JLabel("0");

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        final JFrame f = new JFrame("Sum Combobox");


        Food f1 = new Food("F1", 100);
        Food f2 = new Food("F2", 20);
        c1 = new JComboBox(new Food[] {f1, f2});

        Beverage b1 = new Beverage("B1", 30);
        Beverage b2 = new Beverage("B2", 90);
        c2 = new JComboBox(new Beverage[] {b1, b2});

        c1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                sumLabel.setText(String.valueOf(calculateSum()));
                f.repaint();
            }
        });

        c2.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                sumLabel.setText(String.valueOf(calculateSum()));
                f.repaint();
            }
        });

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(c1);
        p.add(c2);
        p.add(sumLabel);

        f.add(p);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    static int calculateSum() {
        Food selectedFood = (Food) c1.getSelectedItem();
        Beverage selectedBeverage = (Beverage) c2.getSelectedItem();
        return selectedFood.price + selectedBeverage.price;
    }

    static class Food {
        String name;
        int price;

        Food(String name, int price) {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    static class Beverage {
        String name;
        int price;

        Beverage(String name, int price) {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Each time one of your listener is call, you should call a method that will check the selection on each of the ComboBox and return the total price of these item selected.

Answer (score 0):

You could do two things:

The first, you would use JComboBox.getSelectedIndex(), not getItemCount().

Another possibility is just to create a class that has two variables -- the name of the food/beverage and the price.  You'd add a

```
public String toString() { }
```

method to the class that would return the name of the food/beverage, along with the regular getters and setters.  You would populate your combobox with these objects instead.  When you finally call getSelectedItem(), because you're getting an object with the price already in it, you can just call your getPrice() method, instead of hardcoding case statements with fixed prices -- this is usually a bad idea.

Comment: I still don't see how this works properly with getItemCount().  I'm also not a fan of the hard coded case statements with prices.  It works for an assignment, but if you ever code in the real world, you will detest having to do a code update each time there is a price change.

Comment: Actually, I had mistyped that XD
It's `getSelectedIndex()`, indeed.

And this is a project for college, I'm not a professional yet, I'm just learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation on Swings combo box. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html. Are you sure that your methods are firing when an event happens, either by print statements or any other way?

If your methods aren't working, I would make the class that handles events implement from ActionListener and then create an ActionPerformed method. You can decide what to do from there on by checking the source in ActionPerformed.

There is an issue with getItemCount(), that looks like it will return the number of elements in the array that the combobox is using. You need to call getSelectedItem() on your combobox to get the checked item.

Another potential issue is your switch statements, they don't have any defaults. This might not be an issue if you set an initial value for your comboxbox.

I also don't think you can return a value from an ActionPerformed method. I could be wrong but I'm almost positive the system calls that for you when your event happens. This means that theres no variable to stuff the returned price into. You could always use a global variable.

In conclusion, if you follow the link above I think the "Using an Uneditable Combo Box" and "Handling Events on a Combo Box" sections will be of the most use.